Can a Kṣatriya read the Upaniṣads?
Can a Kṣatriya read the Upaniṣads?
Upaniṣads are said to be part of the Vedas, last part of the Vedas to be exact and as far as I know only Brāhmaṇas are allowed to read them. Please clear the doubt.
I am reading Mahābhārata but I feel like I would have better understanding if I read the Upaniṣads (mainly Chāndogya and Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣads).
हरि ॐ

All Dvijas (Brahmins, Kshatriyas and Vaishyas) can read all scriptures after undergoing Upanayana ceremony.


Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, and Vaishyas are called the. twice-born. Their
first births take place when they are delivered of their mother's womb
; their second, when they duly accept the Gayatri Mantra from their
preceptors. (21)
Thus made twice-born, and free from all other faults, they become
entitled to study the Vedas, Smritis and Puranas (22)
Verses 21, 22 from Chapter 1 of Vyasa Smriti

So, after Upanayana a Kshatriya can definitely read Upanishads. The practice is approved by scriptures.
